# How to get notified when an android system property is set (using setprop) in my app?

Tags: java, android, adb, javabeans, propertychangelistener

I came across this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/beans/bean-property-change-event-listener/ wherein there is an example of PropertyChangeListener. In my application I have a Java Thread implementing the runnable interface. I have initialized the PropertyChangeSupport variable in the beginning and registered the PropertyChangeListener. My intention is that when I set a property say debug.xx.yyy using adb shell setprop, I want the propertyChange function call to be triggered. But it is never triggered. Can anyone please point to me where I am going wrong?

Here is my sample code:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
....

public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        MyPropertyChangeSupport myPCS = new MyPropertyChangeSupport();
        myPCS.addMyPCS(new MyPCListener());
        ...
    }

    ...

    public class MyPropertyChangeSupport {
        private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        public void addMyPCS(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            pcs.addPropertyChangeListener("debug.xx.yyy", listener);
        }
    }

    public class MyPCListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            try {
                int oldValue = (Integer) evt.getOldValue();
                int newValue = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();

                if (oldValue == newValue) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ignoring debug property set " + newValue);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got new value " +  newValue);
                    ...
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "debug property does not have integer!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "debug property read encountered NULL!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A) why do you declare the pcs locally in run method? B) If the support shall fire an event, it has to be notified of the change, which you do not. Changing an application property via console won't automagically be seen by the pcs.

Comment: OK so as per (A) should I try making it a member variable of MyThread? I assume that the run function is running on the Java thread hence local variables should be sufficient as they won't be out of scope.

Also as per (B) A property change from adb shell setprop will not kick in for the pcs? So there is no polling on the property somewhere or no state maintainance? I assumed that if property alteration is allowed through adb then there should be support for property change listeners too. If this to not work then can you please suggest me an alternative solution? Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Have a look at the docu of pcs. There is a usage example.

Comment: I looked a little bit around and did not find a way to be notified of system prop changes. Which does not mean, there isn't one. As far as the PropertyChangeSupport is concerned, it is required that the `firePropertyChanged` Method be called to notify listeners. This is not automatically done for system props.

Comment: Yes, seems so. So I checked SystemProperties.java in android frameworks source code. it had an `addChangeCallBack` function. However it would notify for all SystemProperty changes and not the single one I am looking for.

Comment: But they are not changed that frequently. So you could register for that callback and check if the desired prop changed. At least it would be pretty close to your desired functionality and make it possible after all.